# What could be a reason for data to be missing from a Cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra

When I query a table in my Cassandra database (in an EC2 instance), data before 2022-04-15 are not showing. The table had data from November of 2021.

I am new to Cassandra. What could have happened? Last week I exported data to CSV in addition to my usual work.

Comment: For any future Googlers, never EVER use a TTL with `gc_grace_seconds` set to zero.  I've seen this happen before, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data doesn't just magically disappear. There will be a reasonable explanation for it.

There's a good chance that the data has expired, for example if the table has a default TTL of 3 months. However, all we can do is speculate since you haven't provided sufficient information.

As a friendly note, I suggest you learn how to ask good questions. The general guidance is that you (a) provide a good summary of the problem that includes software/component versions, the full error message + full stack trace; (b) describe what you've tried to fix the problem, details of investigation you've done; and (c) minimal sample code that replicates the problem.

In your case, you need to provide the following:

- the schema of the table
- sample query you are running
- details of how your app writes to the table, i.e. does the write query set a TTL?

Cheers!

Comment: TTL has been set. Compaction has happened recently. Unfortunately grace period is also 0. When I check the snapshots folder there is a snapshot created in March 30. Is there a way to recover April data?